# Mouse gestures for Unity desktop

Tags: unity, mouse, shortcuts, gestures

I liked the mouse gesture of Windows 7 to minimize all open windows except the active one. Can I have that kind of gestures to use in Unity.

or **What are the mouse gestures available for Unity?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your general question take a look at [**"What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?"**](https://askubuntu.com/q/28086/46531)

---

For your special question I suggest **Easystroke**:

> Easystroke is a gesture-recognition application for X11. Gestures or strokes are movements that you make with you mouse (or your pen, finger etc.) while holding down a specific mouse button. Easystroke will execute certain actions if it recognizes the stroke; currently easystroke can emulate key presses, execute shell commands, hold down modifiers and emulate a scroll wheel. The program was designed with Tablet PCs in mind and can be used effectively even without access to a keyboard. Easystroke tries to provide an intuitive and efficient user interface, while at the same time being highly configurable and offering many advanced features.

([source](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/))

[image: Install via the software center]

1. To minimize all windows except the active one I refer to [the script in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/40082/46531) (**minimise.py**).
2. To manage Easystroke easily you should make it visible in the panel. For that install [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools], then open **dconf Editor** and switch to `desktop` → `unity` → `panel` and to "systray-whitelist" add `, 'easystroke'` at the end.
3. Then start **Easystroke**. To add a new action click the panel icon and in the `Actions` tab click `Add Action`. Use these parameters:

   - Name: minimize except active
   - Type: command
   - Details: bash -c 'python ~/minimise.py'

   To set a mouse gesture click `Record Stroke` and then while pressing mouse button 2 move the mouse the way you like for this action in future. Ready.
   (You can change the preferred mouse button in `Preferences` tab with a click on `Gesture Button`.)

   [image: easystroke settings]
4. To minimize all windows except the active one now just press mouse button 2 and do the action you chose before.
5. If you like it add Easystroke to Startup Applications by marking as checked "Autostart easystroke" in the `Preferences` tab.

---

How to **configure Easystroke** you can find out in its [Documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/wiki/Documentation) as well as in this [Tips & Tricks](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/wiki/TipsAndTricks) section.

Comment: you can also install xdotool and use 'xdotool key --delay 50ms alt+space key n' to minimize the window

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Easystroke..

You can get it from [Here](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=229797)