# Understanding ubuntu

Tags: development, source-code

I understand that Linux is an open source OS, in other words I have the ability to change whatever I want with the source code of the system. Where is the source code located? For example I would like to add a new event to the mouse which let the user logout when the mouse pointer is moved left then right. Can someone provide me with some lessons or anything that would  me to understand how changes to the Source code happens?

Answer (score 2):

What are you asking is not always so simple.
Here you can find a [guide from title *CompilingEasyHowTo*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo): after you download the source code of the program or package wanted you can modify and recompile it.

It's needed to keep present what is a 
 [Linux_distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) (excerpt from wikipedia):

> A Linux distribution (often called **distro** for short) is an operating system made **as a collection of software** based around the Linux kernel and often around a package management system.
>      ...
>   Most distributions come ready to use and pre-compiled for a specific instruction set, **while others are distributed in source code** form and compiled locally during installation.

So after that you downloaded the source code you can read and modify it before you compile it again. But it is not a trivial task, especially on a running system.

You can start to refer to other posts, [e.g. here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167468/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-ubuntu), to obtain some informations about the source code, how to obtain and so on.

There are may other posts that [can help you on the compiling step](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware), to [locate the source of the kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167468/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-ubuntu), and more generically about [How to install application from source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123077/installing-applications-from-source).

Many programs do not need do be compiled again to choose their settings. Some other yes.
Sometimes you need to install a specific program and you need to search for it.

A way to modify the actions related to the **mouse gestures** is [to install a program that will do it for you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144018/mouse-gestures-for-unity-desktop). The hard way is to compile a kernel module or to modify X system.

A suggestion: go easy at the beginning and increase the difficulties with time and experience.