# How to fix: conky disappears after click on desktop or other window?

Tags: 12.04, window, conky

How to make conky window stay visible after changing the focus, but with desktop icons visible as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get conky to stay on the desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/181663/how-to-get-conky-to-stay-on-the-desktop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit `conky` configuration file, i.e. open in `gedit` from the terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/conky/conky.conf
```

**This worked for me:**

```
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
```

**This worked too, but made desktop icons not visible at all or blinking**

```
own_window no
own_window_type desktop
```

I have also modified `conky` to be movable by removing `undecorated` from:

```
own_window_hints
```

Answer (score 2):

I just removed the line `own_window_type desktop` entirely from the `.conkyrc` file and now conky stays put when I click the desktop in Ubuntu 15.10 with Unity. Why? I dont know. :)

I only use:

```
own_window_class Conky
own_window yes
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
```

Comment: Removed the line from which file?

Comment: From the .conkyrc file. I used Conky Manager and edited the .conkyrc file from the Conky Manager program and just removed the own_window_type desktop (or own_window_type normal) alltogether and that works fine on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately...

In CompizConfig Settings Manager, deselect

**General > General Options > Hide Skip Taskbar Windows**

Answer (score 0):

changing `/etc/conky/conky.conf` or `.conkyrc` doesn't work for me, instead changing the conf file for each widget worked.

for example:

```
gedit ~/.conky/Gotham/Gotham
```

change:

```
own_window_type normal
```

to:

```
own_window_type desktop
```

Comment: This makes conky disappear after clicking desktop. Unlike     own_window_type normal

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. In **ccsm**, deselect

   General > General Options > **Hide Skip Taskbar Windows**
2. own_window_type **normal**

My system is Ubuntu 16.04.3 [Mate 1.16.1]