# Conky disappearing when I show desktop

Tags: 16.04, conky

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to show up my desktop, conky disappears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me with the Cinnamon desktop environment. (Linux Mint 18 - Which is essentially Ubuntu 16.04)

In my conky config:

```
own_window_class Conky
own_window yes
own_window_type dock
```

If that doesn't work in Unity (what comes with Ubuntu, try this)

```
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
```

or

```
own_window no
own_window_type desktop
```

Source: [How to fix: conky disappears after click on desktop or other window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395861/how-to-fix-conky-disappears-after-click-on-desktop-or-other-window)

Comment: Just tried "own_window yes
own_window_type normal". Conky disappeared and wasn't restored with other open windows.

Comment: Just tried "own_window no
own_window_type desktop" and conky disappeared as soon as file was saved (even before showing desktop this time). However I have various other window parameters such as transparent, argb_visual, hints that may conflict with examples given.

Comment: it worked for me.Changed from normal to dock in this line:

own_window_type dock

Comment: dock worked for me. I had tried normal, desktop. desktop disappeared on clicking the desktop and normal flickered on update/redraw

Comment: I have tried normal, desktop and window, none of which have done what I wanted. Dock worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

On Lubuntu 16.04, these worked for me for multiple conky themes:

```
own_window yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_type normal
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu Mate 18.04 and I had the same problem. I changed

```
own_window_type = 'normal',
```

to

```
own_window_type = 'desktop',
```

and the issue seems to be fixed

Comment: Hasn't his answer already been given [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/924930/681688)?

Answer (score 0):

In ~/.conkyrc

```
own_window = false,
own_window_class = 'conky',
own_window_type = 'desktop'
```

worked for me with Unity.  It still disappears momentarily, but it comes back as soon as it updates.

Comment: might help if you mention which file to edit :)

Answer (score -1):

In my case:

```
Operating System: Manjaro Linux
KDE Plasma Version: 5.23.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.90.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.15.16-1-MANJARO (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz
Memory: 31.2 ГиБ of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620
```

I use this settings additional to default settings:

```
own_window = true,
own_window_hints = 'undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',
own_window_transparent = true,
own_window_type = 'normal',
```

in ~.config/conky/conky.conf

And the issue has been fixed.

Thanks to [Mehrdad Salimi](https://askubuntu.com/a/920727/1568051)

Comment: Your answer for for another Linux not Ubuntu.